# ASP.net nlog create time wise file

Tags: asp.net, nlog

I need to create file date wise, though folder is creating now.

But I need to put date wise file in run time folder

```
String logfile = t.FileName.ToString() + "/" + LoginID + "DateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd").txt";

t.FileName = logfile;
```

`LoginID` is the value taken from database and changes folder on fly, but need to create text file . I am stucked here.

Any Help ?

Comment: Could you post the configuration?